# How to add row to EXISTING Datatable

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net-2010

I have an sql database (agentroster.sdf) in my Visual Basic 2010 Express solution, and I have been able to create a data source (AGENT_ROSTER), with the datatable. All this works, as far as I can tell.

However, I am trying to add a new row to this existing datatable (and thus, database) from ROSTER.xaml.vb, which is in the same project as the database. I will also need to delete records, and load a records' values into a set of variables, which will later be written back after changing. This system is necessary for my particular project.

However, I cannot figure out how to create a new row in this EXISTING datatable. I've already confirmed the connections and everything, and I don't want to have to create an entirely new connection on top of the existing one.

Help?

Comment: Can you give the code you have tried? Are you getting any error while trying to add a new row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can do something similar to this:

```
    var table = new DataTable();
    var row = table.NewRow();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Of course table is essentially empty at this point but if your datatable came from a database then it has schema already and the new row will match it's schema.

Comment: Thank you. Pardon if this is a dumb question, but how does this code know to base this datatable off of the database "agentroster", if this code is in my form's button_click code? My connection is on a global level, that is, it shows up in Visual Basic 2010 Express' "Database Connections" pane - it isn't created in the form code.

Comment: This specific code won't - that's why I said that the table in the code above is essentially empty - if you were using YOUR datatable from YOUR datasource - then the schema of the datatable is already set.  extracting a new empty row, with all the proper columns, from that schema is done with the table.NewRow() and then that row can be added into your datatable with the table.Rows.Add(row) code.

Comment: For some reason, this code wasn't working. I used agentroster.NewRow, and it said that agentroster (the name of the datatable) did not have that property.

Comment: I'm using "|" to separate lines. Remember that I have AGENT_ROSTER declared in data sources. CODE: Dim roster_table As New DataTable("AGENT_ROSTER") | 'This part of the code goes in the button click event class. | Dim NewRow As DataRow = roster_table.NewRow() | NewRow("DATA_NAME") = txtAgent.Text | roster_table.Rows.Add(NewRow)